# Invalid use of template name ' ' without an argument list

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, stack, nodes

I'm trying to create simple stack using linked lists in C++. Suddenly I encountered the problem which is (I think) connected with templates. I lack knowledge in that structures thats why I tried to create something and learn with it.
My problem is with `node * top;` what should I change ? any idea?
My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>

class node {
public:
  T object;
  node * next;
};

node *top = NULL;

template<typename T>
class Stack{

public:
  void push(T obj);
  void pop();
  void display(ostream & out) const;
};

void Stack :: push(T obj){

  node * tempNode = new node;
  tempNode->object = obj;
  tempNode->next = top;
  top = tempNode;
}

void Stack :: display(ostream & out) const{

    if(top == NULL){
      cout << "Stack is Empty"<<endl;
      return;
     }
     else{

       node *temp = top;
       while(temp!=NULL){

         cout << "Here is your elements :"<<"\n";
         cout << temp->object<<endl;
         temp = temp->next;
       }
       cout <<endl;
     }
}

void Stack :: pop(){

  if (top = NULL){
    cout << "List is Empty"<<endl;
    return;
  }

  cout << "Your object: "<<top->object << " is removed"<<endl;
  top = top->next;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Stack & s){
  s.display(out);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question.

Comment: no offense, but in general, guessing c++ syntax is not recommended. Guessing syntax for templates is close to impossible

Comment: please include sample input and output (for expected and current); any errors that are displayed. read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `node` is a template, you must use `<>` to specify template parameters every time you use it. There are certain situations (starting from C++17) when compiler can deduce template parameters, but it's going to be easier to just add `<T>` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `top` should be a member of `Stack` not a global variable? You also need to specify the template type of `node`:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack{
  node<T> *top = NULL;

public:
  void push(T obj);
  void pop();
  void display(ostream & out) const;
};
```

When defining methods of templated classes out of line you need to specify the template type for the class:

```
template<typename T>
void Stack<T> :: push(T obj){
```

Your `<<` operator also needs to be a template:

```
template<typename T>
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Stack<T> & s){
  s.display(out);
  return out;
}
```